# AudioKit swift panning

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, audiokit

Im currently developing an app with the help from audioKit. Im trying to pan the audio so it only plays in one ear at a time. Any ideas of what might be wrong?

The sound is playing, but It plays simultaneously in both ears.

```
func createTone(freq: Double, dB: Int, isLeftEar: Bool){
        currentFreq = Int(freq)
        currentdB = dB
        isAudioOn = true
        osciliator.frequency = freq
        osciliator.amplitude = calculateVolume(dB: dB)
        osciliator.rampDuration = 0.25
        let leftPan = AKPanner(osciliator, pan: -1)
        let rightPan = AKPanner(osciliator, pan: 1)
        if(isLeftEar){
            AudioKit.AKManager.output = leftPan
            
        }else{
            
            AudioKit.AKManager.output = rightPan
        }
        do{
            try AudioKit.AKManager.start()
        }catch{
            print("could not start AudioKit.")
        }
        
        if isLeftEar {
            leftPan.start()
        }else{
            rightPan.start()
        }
        
        osciliator.start()
        sleep(2)
        
        do{
            try AudioKit.AKManager.stop()}
        catch{
            print("AudioKit could not stop")
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, nodes are declared at class level instead of as local variables. So you would have something like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var panner: AKPanner!

func createTone(freq: Double, dB: Int, isLeftEar: Bool){
    // ...

    panner = AKPanner(oscillator, pan: (isLeftEar) ? -1 : 1)
    // ...
}
```

Also, `sleep` should never be called in the main thread. You should rather use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
    do{
        try AKManager.stop()}
    catch{
        print("AudioKit could not stop")
    }
}
```

### Update

I tested the following code with AudioKit 4.10.1 and it did pan correctly to the left channel.

```
var panner: AKPanner!
var oscillator: AKOscillator!

func createTone(){
    oscillator = AKOscillator()
    panner = AKPanner(oscillator, pan: -1)
    AKManager.output = panner
    do{
        try AudioKit.AKManager.start()
    }catch{
        print("could not start AudioKit.")
    }
    
    panner.start()
    oscillator.start()
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 20.0) {
        do {
            try AudioKit.AKManager.stop()
        } catch {
            print("AudioKit could not stop")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did not solve the problem. Although thanks for the formatting.

Comment: I'll try to test it, which version of AudioKit are you using?

Comment: I tested with AudioKit version 4.10.1 and it panned correctly to the left channel. I've updated my answer with the code I used to test.